# Symmetric pairing function for two numbers

Tags: c++, dictionary, math

I want to create a unique key where **the value of i,j is equal to the value for j,i.** I will use that for a C++ map.

I have a fixed number of elements I want to have inside this map and also i and j are both major or equal than 0.

For example:

i , j

0,1 -> 4

1,0 -> 4

3,4 -> 9

4,3 -> 9

However I can't seem to find a way. Is there something efficient to do that in C++?

Comment: Write a struct that has two `int` members and implements comparison functions always comparing the smaller to the smaller and the larger to the larger member.

Comment: Do the numbers have an upper limit?

Comment: @user1810087 yes, there's a maximum number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there exists a number N that is greater than `i` or `j`:

```
uint32_t unique_key(uint32_t i, uint32_t j) {
  if (i < j)
    return i * N + j;
  else
    return j * N + i;
}
```

Comment: if I'm not wrong, expectation from the question is to generate `key(i,j)== key(j,i)`

Comment: Worth mentioning in this case, `N` cannot be greater than 65535.

Comment: @TruthSeeker Can you come up with a counterexample where this is not so?

Comment: @Botje : As mentioned in question, Even Zero(0) could be valid input, then `(0,x)` produces `x` whereas '(x,0)' produces `x*N` where `x>0`

Comment: Opps, I'm wrong at test case. function produces symmetric o/p. +1 from my side.

Comment: Why not just use a type of double the size for the key and memcpy the sorted values into it. This can be implemented without any requirements on the original type and a magic number. Otherwise we cannot cover the full value range.

Comment: That works too, but is equivalent to N=2**32. OP did not specify what the upper limit was and what the resulting type should be.